# PostgreSQL: Column VS Array

Tags: postgresql, database-design

First of all, I should say that I have never dealt with such big data before, and I have not worked much with any databases, and I actually have little understanding of it.

I have a lot of files and data in them is stored in JSON format. I need to handle these files and put the results in the database, and then work with the data from the database. My choice was between PostgreSQL and MongoDB. I chose PostgreSQL because I read that it performs much faster.

At the moment, I'm focusing on the structure of the database itself so that the data can be quickly and easily used. Since I have little experience, I was wondering which structure to choose and how best to store the data.

I choose between the next two:

**1. for each port to create its own column (if necessary)**

something like

```
 ip       | port_80 | port_8888 | port_353 |
-----------+-----------------------------------+-
 12.0.0.4 |    1    |      0    |     1    |
```

**2. use an array**

something like

```
 ip       |       ports      | 
-----------+-----------------------+-
 12.0.0.4 | data{80,888,353} |
```

What exactly would you advise to choose?

*How much data?*

Files are around 300 gigabytes. How much of this is going to be in the database I can't tell you.

P.S. I'd be glad to be pointed to links that explain such simple things and explain how to use databases correctly. Thx.

Comment: Much of the answer depends on what you plan to do with the data.  Is this something you need to store and then retrieve from time to time when you don't mind waiting a little while for results?  Or is this something you will be actively reporting on and constantly scanning for whatever purpose?  Also, is this time series data?  You will need to plan for retention activities.  I just saw @AdrianKlaver's answer, and I endorse what he suggests.

Comment: @MikeOrganek
I'm going to have to search for information among all these data. Minor delays are acceptable. The data will be updated once a month, I do not think it will be more often.

Comment: Thank you.  When you say, "update," do you mean you will drop it and load again?  The reason I ask is because if you let it accumulate month to month it is a nightmare to maintain without partitioning.  Also, I again point you to @AdrianKlaver's solution.  That is the most correct way to do it.  See also https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-net-types.html for how to store IP addresses, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-net.html for how to work with them, and store your port numbers as `integers` for major size and speed advantages.

Comment: @MikeOrganek Thank you for the links! Yes, I planned to drop the database and upload new data as soon as it was available.

Answer (score 1):

Third choice:

```
ip       |       port      | 
-----------+-------------------
 12.0.0.4 | 80
 12.0.0.4 | 888
 12.0.0.4 | 353

UNIQUE(ip, port)
```

Then you don't have to hard code port numbers into column names or do a double retrieval by pulling up `ports` and then walking through another structure. With the `UNIQUE` you ensure that you only have one port number assigned to an IP.

Comment: Thank you. So far it looks more massive to me, i.e. it looks like this option will use more "space"/"volume",  so more power and time to process it. But it looks like I'm wrong. Could you explain why this is wrong?

Comment: I think you are suggesting that the combination of `(ip, port)` should be unique, which would make sense since that is the natural key for this table. You might want to clarify that in your answer.

Comment: @Z4-tier. @KarlsD has not provided enough information to determine whether there is more data going in and whether there is a better candidate for a PK.  I'm just saying it would be help to keep (ip, port) ```UNIQUE``` for it's own sake.

Comment: @KarlsD. The data will be there in one form or another. I'm guessing you have not given us all the information that is going in, so it will be hard to make any statements about which is best at this point. The thing to do is to create different tables using the different options and load them with some non-trivial amount of data and see what happens.